# Finding repetition of string pattern in a given string

Tags: c++

Could someone answer the below C++ interview question:

Given string:     "song singing in hindi"

find repeated strings like as below :

```
single characters repetition:
```

Count of "s" = 2   Count of "o" = 0     Count of "n" = 5    Count of "g" = 3
  .....  etc

```
two character repetition
```

Count of "so" = 0    Count of "on" = 0     Count of "ng" = 3     Count of "in" = 4.....  etc

```
Three character repetition
```

Count of "son" = 0 ....Count of "ing" = 1....  etc

```
Four character repetition
```

Count of "song" = 0   .....etc

Rs

Comment: What question are we supposed to answer?

Comment: _"Could someone answer the below C++ interview question"_ - Yes, many of us could but unless you put some effort into solving the problem yourself it's unlikely anyone will. if you can't solve this problem on your own you're not the right candidate for the position.

Comment: I'd start with `std::map` or `std::unordered_map`. With either of those, the task should be pretty trivial.

Comment: @shaik786 Why is there Count of "o" = 0 and not Count of "o" = 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or even a recursive function would do. To remove the 'patterns' with a white space you can follow Vlad's approach with the string::find function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class FRQ {
    void Func(std::map<std::string, size_t> &frequencyTable, const std::string &m_str, const int stepping = 1) {
        if (stepping == m_str.size()) {
            frequencyTable[m_str]++;
            return;
        }

        for (std::string::size_type i = 0, iMAX = m_str.size(); i < iMAX; ++i) {
            frequencyTable[m_str.substr(i, stepping)]++;
        }

        Func(frequencyTable, m_str, stepping + 1);
    }
public:
    std::map<std::string, size_t> *operator()(const std::string &str) {
        std::map<std::string, size_t> *fTable = new std::map<std::string, size_t>();

        Func(*fTable, str);

        return fTable;
    }
};

int main(void) {
    using namespace std;

    string s = "HiYo HiYo";

    FRQ frq;
    map<string, size_t> *frequenceTable = frq(s);

    cout << "Patterns: " << frequenceTable->size() << endl;
    for (const auto& ptr : *frequenceTable)
        cout << "[ '" << ptr.first << "'::" << ptr.second << " ]" << endl;

    delete frequenceTable;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If we have to solve this problem without STL's or any built-in API's, then how we will resolve this. Could some one let me know, If any Algorithm exist for this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward approach

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main() 
{
    std::string s =  "song singing in hindi";

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 1; i <= s.size(); i++ )
    {
        std::map<std::string, size_t> m;

        for ( std::string::size_type j = 0; j < s.size() - i + 1; j++ )
        {
            m[std::string( s, j, i )]++;
        }

        for ( const auto &p : m )
        {
            std::cout << "( \"" << p.first << "\", " << p.second << " ) ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to exclude patters with an embedded blank you can rewrite the program the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main() 
{
    std::string s =  "song singing in hindi";

    for ( std::string::size_type i = 1; i <= s.size(); i++ )
    {
        std::map<std::string, size_t> m;

        for ( std::string::size_type j = 0; j < s.size() - i + 1; j++ )
        {
            std::string t( s, j, i );
            if ( t.find( ' ' ) == std::string::npos )
            {
                m[t]++;
            }
        }

        if ( !m.empty() )
        {
            for ( const auto &p : m )
            {
                std::cout << "( \"" << p.first << "\", " << p.second << " ) ";
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
( "d", 1 ) ( "g", 3 ) ( "h", 1 ) ( "i", 5 ) ( "n", 5 ) ( "o", 1 ) ( "s", 2 ) 
( "di", 1 ) ( "gi", 1 ) ( "hi", 1 ) ( "in", 4 ) ( "nd", 1 ) ( "ng", 3 ) ( "on", 1 ) ( "si", 1 ) ( "so", 1 ) 
( "gin", 1 ) ( "hin", 1 ) ( "ind", 1 ) ( "ing", 2 ) ( "ndi", 1 ) ( "ngi", 1 ) ( "ong", 1 ) ( "sin", 1 ) ( "son", 1 ) 
( "ging", 1 ) ( "hind", 1 ) ( "indi", 1 ) ( "ingi", 1 ) ( "ngin", 1 ) ( "sing", 1 ) ( "song", 1 ) 
( "hindi", 1 ) ( "ingin", 1 ) ( "nging", 1 ) ( "singi", 1 ) 
( "inging", 1 ) ( "singin", 1 ) 
( "singing", 1 )
```

Comment: If we have to solve this problem without STL's or any built-in API's, then how we will resolve this. Could some one let me know, If any Algorithm exist for this pattern